# Why does a panel of glass appear translucent when viewed from the edge?

Tags: refraction

Why does this happen?

[image: image of glass panel]

From the 'front' of the panel, the glass appears transparent. But viewed from the 'edges', it appears translucent...

Comment: Well, actually, it's not translucent, just refracted and reflected so that you are looking through a _lot_ more glass, pretty much from edge-to-edge. Since most glass is greenish in color, that gives you the greenish color you see in this case. Notice that even in this picture you can see some specific details, just refracted and reflected at odd angles.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! So, does that mean if the glass pane was the same _height_ as it is _width_ such that it's a cube, that the glass would look greenish from all angles??

Comment: Also why does reflection come into play?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right, and you can even try it if you can find a piece of glass with a square cross section. Reflection comes into play through what is called _internal reflection_, when something with a high index of refraction (glass) touches something with a low index of refraction (air). You can see the same effect by looking at the water surface through the end of an aquarium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the comments have touched up on this, the light reaching the glass is experiencing internal refraction. The same reason that when [fabric gets wet it seems to get darker](http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2010/11/11/3063513.htm). The same thing is happening inside the glass before reaching your eye.

[image: What total internal reflection looks like.]

This is what you are seeing in the glass but it would look someone more like this picture:
[image]

When the light hits the glass more of it is adsorbed into the impurities in the glass making it seem darker and greener. The glass (which has essentially been turned into a mirror now) is not as good at reflecting the other colors as green which is why putting a mirror next to another mirror makes that greenish hue that you see in the following picture:
[image]

Comment: Incidentally I just came across this article which explains a bit more, [why is glass green?](http://blogs.howstuffworks.com/keep-asking/if-you-look-at-a-piece-of-glass-from-an-angle-why-does-it-have-a-bluish-or-green-tint.htm)